# Access The Unbonding Amount With Substrate Query

Tags: staking, substrateinterface

I'm trying to measure the unbonding amount directly from a substrate-interface query.

Here's the amount I'm interested in:

[image: unbonding amount]

I can get some account information with this query:

`value = self.active_substrate.query('System', 'Account', params=[self.ss58_address]).value`

But this returns

```
{
                'nonce': value['nonce'],
                'consumers': value['consumers'],
                'providers': value['providers'],
                'sufficients': value['sufficients'],
                'coin_units': self.config.coinName,
                'free': free,
                'reserved': reserved,
                'misc_frozen': misc_frozen,
                'fee_frozen': fee_frozen
}
```

Unless I'm missing something, there's no way to derive the unbonding amount from this result. Is there a better / different query to use for these details? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the amount of funds being unlocked in the Staking pallet, and so you should query the Staking storage. I am not super familiar with `substrate-interface`, so this may just be pseudo code:

```
value = self.active_substrate.query('Staking', 'Ledger', params=[self.ss58_address]).value
```

In this you should see an `unlocking` field which has the list of funds that are pending to be unlocked (unbonding).

Comment: Thanks, Shawn! Quick follow up, it looks like this returns unlocking WND in terms of the era it becomes available. Ex: 'unlocking': [{'value': 1000000000000, 'era': 5064}, {'value': 4000000000000, 'era': 5066}, {'value': 2000000000000, 'era': 5069}]. Do you know how to query the current era as well?